# what is difference between the two functions in aws acl

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I'm practicing deployment using aws s3 and cloudFront.

The issue I met was that account B approached S3, which made by account A, and uploaded the object using Github Actions.

I solved this issue with changing two things.

First, I added external account with Grantee in S3 ACL like picture.

[image]

Second, I added code in `.yml` file `--acl bucket-owner-full-control` like below for Github Actions.

```yaml
...

- name: S3 Deploy
  run: aws s3 sync ./dist s3://s3-bucket-name/ --acl bucket-owner-full-control
```

Both two options are set, the function is working.

But, I don't understand why this option `--acl bucket-owner-full-control` is needed.

I thought the first setting was enough for account B to access S3 owned by account A.

I found something that may be related to this topic. Is it related to this issue?

[image]

Comment: When you say "I think account B can access S3, which owned account A", do you mean "I know that account B can access the S3 bucket owned by account A"?

Comment: I think the sentence caused confusion. sorry. that sentence is not needed.